# How to integrate KeePass2 and Firefox using Kee in Ubuntu 18.04 - 22.04?

Tags: 20.04, firefox, 22.04, firefox-extensions, keepass

I have already Installed KeePass2 and also installed both Add-ons Kee. But I don't know how to integrate it.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: i would rather use [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/) or even better [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/). a auto-type function (at least for *nix-OSes) is already built.

Comment: Do you think you could fix the typo in the subject line (it's KeePass2 and not KeyPass2) to make this even more useful?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Ubuntu 22.04

**Install KeyPass2:**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start terminal and run following commands one by one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/keepass2  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install keepass2 mono-complete xdotool
```

Open Firefox, install `Kee` from Add-on
[image]

Tools>Add-ons

Search for `Kee` and install it.

Open as Administrator (Access), skip if you have it, if not follow the step.

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
nautilus -q
```

Download KeePassRPC plugins
[KeePassRPC.plgx](https://github.com/kee-org/keepassrpc/releases)

Right click plugins (/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins) folder select
"Open as Administrator"

Copy Paste the latest version of KeePassRPC into the plugins folder

```
/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins
```

You're all done!

Answer (score 28):

### Ubuntu 14.04, 15.10 / Linux Mint 17

First, you neither need `PassIFox` nor the extra PPA describe by *@Faisal Haq Salafi* as `mono-complete` and `keepass2` are already **available in the repository**.

### Installation

1. [Download & Install KeeFox add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keefox/)
2. install `keepass2` and `mono` CLI compiler and system manager library:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install keepass2 mono-dmcs libmono-system-management4.0-cil libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil
   ```

   - **upvote** [Faisal Haq Salafi](https://askubuntu.com/a/291309/22343) for answer basis;
   - **upvote** [Simounet](https://askubuntu.com/a/702794/22343) for narrowing down the package list (6Mo vs. 125Mo with `mono-complete`);

### Configuration

- KeePass plugin location: `/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins`
- Keefox

  - KeePass installation location: `/usr/lib/keepass2`
  - Mono executable location: `/usr/bin/mono`

#### KeePassRPC plugin

```bsh
# create a plugins sub-directory in keepass2 directory
sudo sh -c 'mkdir /usr/lib/keepass2/plugins' 
# copy the keefox plugin into it
sudo ln --force --no-dereference --symbolic $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/extensions/keefox@chris.tomlinson/deps/KeePassRPC.plgx /usr/lib/keepass2/plugins/
```

### Restart

Quit and restart both:

1. Keepass2, then unlock your vault;
2. Firefox, check keefox icon for information

Comment: Instead of copying the plugin, I think creating a symbolic link would be more sensible so there's no problem with updates: `sudo ln -s $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/extensions/keefox@chris.tomlinson/deps/KeePassRPC.plgx /usr/lib/keepass2/plugins/KeePassRPC.plgx`

Comment: @ThomasW. you are right, I updated my answer accordingly (note you don't need to specify the filename on the target, it will use the original filename)

Answer (score 8):

[Edited on 04/29/2016]

Since the 1.6.0 version of KeeFox, this trick is not working. New libs are required. At the moment, I found `libmono2.0-cil` but there is more. I posted [a topic on the the KeeFox forum](https://zohodiscussions.com/keefox#Topic/71684000000903029).

[Original post]

KeeFox don't need everything from mono, so it's useless to install `mono-complete`. `mono-dmcs` and `libmono-system-management4.0-cil` must be enough. So, this command must do the trick:

`sudo apt-get install keepass2 mono-dmcs libmono-system-management4.0-cil`

With this method, you'll spare more than 120Mo and a bunch of useless lib to keep up to date.
I get this requirement from the KeeFox GitHub wiki: https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/wiki/en-|-Running-KeeFox-under-Mono

Comment: Is there a minimal version of ubuntu for this statement? I'm testing on Kubuntu 15.10

Comment: Work on Kubuntu 15.10

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `mono-dmcs` and `libmono-system-management4.0-cil` are available on 12.04. So it must be no problem with newer versions.

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 I needed mono-mcs, since mono-dmcs was not available anymore

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 16.04

If You have **KeePass 2** installed, then there is a convenient way to keep everything up to date and working.

> If you do not know what PPA-s are, please do read this: [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for)

### Install

> **NOTE:** You may need to undo the manual installment on KeeFox!

Add a ppa, and install **KeeFox** from there:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dlech/keepass2-plugins
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xul-ext-keefox
```

This will also install the **RPC** plugin (`keepass2-plugin-rpc`) as its dependency.

### Configure

as descibed by *@Édouard-lopez*

- Keefox

  - KeePass installation location: `/usr/lib/keepass2`
  - Mono executable location: `/usr/bin/mono`

### Benefits:

- No need to manually copy the `KeePassRPC.plgx` file
- Contains the mono libraries needed (and keeps them up to date)
- Other plugins are also available (that help integrate keepass2 into ubuntu, eg `keepass2-plugin-application-indicator`)

#### (check for older versions needed!)

---

#### Edit

- Installing `xul-ext-keefox` instead of `keepass2-plugin-rpc` ensures version compatibility

Answer (score 0):

For **Ubuntu 18.04**
From the Ubuntu Software search and install KeePassXc
[KeePassXC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYlib.png)

In FireFox, in Add-ons (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl +  Shift +  A</kbd>) search for [KeePassXC-Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keepassxc-browser/) Add to Firefox.

Open KeePassXC and open your KeePass database, then go to

> Tools -> Settings -> Browser Integration
>   [KeePassXC Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Xfv.jpg)

Make Sure you check

1. Enable KeePassXC browser integration
2. FireFox option is seleced in the Enable integration for these browsers

Then in FireFox click on the newly added KeePassXC-Browser button and then in the Connect button
A new KeePassXC: New key association request window opens, type in the name of your database and Save and allow access.

That's it, KeePassXC is now integrated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Why should we use KeePassXC and KeePassXC-Browser over keepass2 and Kee? Is keepass2 + Kee unsafe?

(I am not suggesting we shouldn't, I'm just confused with all the different forks and would like to know which one is best/safest, and I'm already used to keepass2 + Kee on Ubuntu 16.04.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion of KeePass with plugins on Ubuntu and either browser integration in general and that is more current: "KeePass and Ubuntu 20.04 Setup (with Chrome, Firefox)?" [KeePass and Ubuntu 20.04 Setup (with Chrome, Firefox)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228389/keepass-and-ubuntu-20-04-setup-with-chrome-firefox)